# DynamoDB tables created with NodeJS not displayed in AWS Explorer

Tags: .net, node.js, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2015, amazon-dynamodb

I'm writing aws lambda function that reads the data from dynamodb table using VS2015.
I created few tables in AWS explorer in VS that shipped with AWS SDK.
Weird thing is that I don't see these tables in node js code.
Same thing happens when I create tables using node js: AWS explorer doesn't display them, however ARNs are similar: arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000:table/TABLENAME
and table statuses are ACTIVE.
Here is my configuration:

```
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "someId",
    secretAccessKey: "someKey",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:10000"
});
```

Any solution?

Comment: What about AWS region?

Comment: I don't specify it. Should I provide some special value when deploying db locally?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are not running dynamodb local(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html)

Dynamodb as service supports region, you should ideally specify that.

But if you want to continue with endpoint, choose from one of the values available here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ddb_region

Answer (score 0):

Your table ARN:

> arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000:table/TABLENAME

and nodejs configuration:

```
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "someId",
    secretAccessKey: "someKey",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:10000"
});
```

seem to indicate that your nodejs code is using a locally-deployed DynamoDB server, rather than an AWS-hosted server.

Most likely, your AWS Explorer is looking at DynamoDB in a particular region, and it's not looking at your local server.

Make sure, in the AWS Explorer, that your region is set to "Local (localhost)".

Note that before you upload your Lambda code to AWS, you'll need to modify the configuration to use a real region.

Comment: In AWS Explorer Local (localhost) region is selected and two tables are displayed, which I created from Explorer and C#, but no tables that I created from NodeJS code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to make it refer to the same db from Node and AWS Explorer.
Key Id and Access Key are make profile which should be the same when working with AWS Explorer and Node.
When running DB locally, the next format for db name is used: KEYID_REGION.db
so that's why providing valid settings is necessary.
In Node JS when region setting is not provided, default region is used which is 'us-west-1'. If region is provided, and db is accessed from code, another db will be created with provided region name. 
However, there is one thing: it seems that by default Local region in AWS Explorer supports only 'us-east-1' region, so if you create tables in another local region, you won't see these tables in Explorer.